# Handlebars inside place holder

Tags: .net, handlebars.net

Is it possible with handlebars for .NET do something like this:

```
var data = new { 
    title = "my title",
    body = "my body, look at {{title}}"
}
```

I mean is it possible to use handlebar inside handlebars-value.
Then I have template:

```
string source = @"
  <b>Title</b> {{title}} <br/>
  <b>Body</b> {{body}}
";
```

And I would like to have:

```
<b>Title</b> my title <br/>
<b>Body</b> my body, look at my title
```

I know this is looks slightly weird, in this case we can easilly split body and title, but it's not my real project, just similiar example, I cannot make such splitting in real project.
Does anyone know is it possible do such things with handlebars or not? And if it is possible then how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines using `string.Format()` method

Comment: No I can't, this isn't the case; I have HTML handlebars template, and page model with lots of hierarchical properties, one of them is {{FreeText}} which is read from DB and inside this text I would like to insert "sub-handlebar" value.

Comment: OK. Do you know in advance what the names of the handlebar template fields are going to be?  If so, why not code such as source.Replace(@"{title}",data.title).  If you don't want to hard-code the names the fields then this can also be done using reflection - its a bit more work but I can point you in the right direction

Comment: Yeah. We thought about it and seems we will do something like this, I just wanted to find nicer solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but you need to do a little extra work to make it happen. And it may not perform well, since unless you get more sophisticated, you will have to recompile the template each time you run it. Here's roughly how it would work:

```
Handlebars.RegisterHelper("template", (output, context, arguments) =>
    {
        var template = Handlebars.Compile((string)arguments[0]);
        var result = template(context);
        output.WriteSafeString(result);
    });
```

And your template would look like:

```
<b>Title</b> {{title}} <br/>
<b>Body</b> {{template body}}
```